# '98 Legacy Outback (DOHC EJ 25) timing belt doesn't have marks

Tags: engine, subaru, timing-belt

I'm changing the timing belt on my '98 Legacy Outback, but the replacement timing belt I got doesn't seem to have marks on it for alignment.  I already took off the other belt, and it doesn't have marks either.  Does anyone know how may teeth apart each mark is?

1998 Subaru Legacy Outback
DOHC EJ25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in service info. Including the alignment marks diagram.

[image]

Location : Number Of Teeth
Z-1 : 54.5
Z-2 : 51
Z-3 : 28

[image]